# How to mix the processing of a Java string

Tags: java, string

Java string contains two types of words. 
Words of first Type are:

```
Wx1,Wx2,Wx3,Wx4,Wx5,Wx6, Wx7 etc.
```

Words of second Type are:

```
Wy1,Wy2 etc.
```

Given

```
String str= "Wx1 Wx2   Wy1   Wx3 Wx4   Wy2    Wx5 Wx7 Wx8"
```

First type is processed by function1(),  Second type function2(), and function3() further processes  the concatenated output of function1().

```
function1(Wx1) gives String S1
function1(Wx2) gives String S2
String S12= S1 + S2;
    function3(S12) returns String str1


function2(Wy1) gives String Y1

function1(Wx3) gives String S3
function1(Wx4) gives String S4

String S34= S3 + S4;
    function3(S34) returns String str2

    function2(Wy2) gives String Y2

function1(Wx5) gives String S5
function1(Wx6) gives String S6
function1(Wx7) gives String S7
function1(Wx8) gives String S8

String S5678 = S5 + S6 + S7 + S8
    function3(S5678) returns String str3


String output = str1 + Y1+ str2 + Y2 + str3;

This is the whole logic my program.
```

I am confused at last step to shape the loop that where and how to call the function3():

```
for(int i=0; i<Words.length; i++){

if Word[i]= Type1??????????{ doThis(); ?????

//somewhere here I have to call function3(), how the program will judge that the next word is of type2, hence function3 is to be called here.// WHERE AND HOW TO CALL function3();
    }
else {doThat();
}
```

Being new to Programming I need the help to form the logic of the loop.

Comment: You're looking for _patterns_.

Comment: What's the difference between type 1 words and type 2 words?  When you can answer that question in English or your native language, then you can translate your requirement into code.

Comment: first type starts with figures like 1h,2h,5k etc. and second type starts with alphabets like fsh,ggk,nas, ilk etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused about the multiple creation of Strings S12, S34 etc. At the end your result should be `S12 + Y1+ S34 + Y2 + S5678;`. This is equivalent to `S1 + S2 + Y1 + S3 + S4 + Y2 + S5 + S6 + S7 + S8`. So is there any point in creating those intermediate concatenation here? If not you could try this program.

**EDIT :**

```
public class MixProcessor {
    private static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str= "Wx1 Wx2 Wy1 Wx3 Wx4 Wy2 Wx5 Wx7 Wx8";
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        String previousPatter = "";
        boolean shouldMerge = false;

        for(String s : str.split(" ")){
            String processedString = "";

            if (s.matches(".*?x.*")){
                shouldMerge = ("x".equals(previousPatter) || previousPatter.trim().length() == 0) ? true : false;
                previousPatter = "x";
                processedString = function1(s);
            } else if (s.matches(".*?y.*")){
                shouldMerge = ("y".equals(previousPatter) || previousPatter.trim().length() == 0) ? true : false;
                previousPatter = "y";
                processedString = function2(s);
            }

            if(shouldMerge){
                temp.append(processedString);
            } else {
                output.append(function3(temp.toString()));
                temp = new StringBuilder(processedString);
            }
        }
        //Append the last value
        output.append(function3(temp.toString()));

        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }

    private static String function2(String s) {
        return "Y" + s.substring(s.indexOf("y") + 1);
    }

    private static String function1(String s) {
        return "S" + s.substring(s.indexOf("x") + 1);
    }

    private static String function3(String s) {
        // Here this could be any function. I'm just trying to make as per the question
        return (s.indexOf("S") != -1) ? ("str" + (++counter)) : s;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your solution has cleared me a lot. I  have edited my question and have included function3() to clear my 'multiple creation' of strings and to refine the explanation my needs. Now I expect some more suitable solution from you, kindly do that.

Comment: That should be easy with some booleans and if-else. Updated my answer. May be that'll help. :)

Comment: Answer has been updated, but really I need your further help.

Comment: Sure. Tell me. What further help do you need?

Comment: Your latest guidelines are quite perfect. If I'll find any difficulty in implementing it, I shall request you.